# In ZF, when is a disjoint union of metrizable spaces metrizable?

Tags: gn.general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is easy to see that the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_i X_i$ of a collection of
metric spaces is metrizable, simply by rescaling or chopping off
the individual metrics to have diameter at most one, and then
making points in the various components distance two apart. This
produces a metric on the disjoint union giving the disjoint union
topology.

A subtle point arises, however, if we are given not a collection
of metric spaces, but instead merely a collection of metrizable
topological spaces $X_i$, where a particular metric has not yet been
chosen. In this case, in order to carry out the construction
above, we would need first to choose a particular metric realizing
the metrizability of each space, and this would seem to require
the axiom of choice.

**Question.** Without assuming the axiom of choice, when is the
disjoint union of a set of metrizable spaces metrizable?

One can see that some choice is definitely required by the
following argument. Suppose that we are given a collection of
countable sets $S_i$. Let's regard these sets as discrete
topological spaces and let $S_i^+$ be the corresponding one-point
compactification, which is metrizable, since each $S_i$ is
countable. If we had a metric on the disjoint union $\bigcup
S_i^{+}$, however, we could consider the largest ball at the new
point in each $S_i^+$ to omit some elements of $S_i$, and this
would provide us with a canonical choice of non-empty finite sets
$T_i\subset S_i$. But the existence of such a kind of choice
surely requires some form of choice. Thus, in general, we cannot
prove without any AC that the disjoin union of metrizable spaces
is metrizable.

So what I seek is a nice sufficient condition for making this
conclusion. Here is one answer: given a family of metrizable
spaces $X_i$ suppose there exists a finite family of distinct
metrizable spaces $M_j$ such that

(1) each $M_j$ has a metric that makes every topological automorphism of $M_j$ an isometry; and

(2) but for finitely many $i$, each $X_i$ is homeomorphic to some $M_j$.

(Given an $X_i$ and a homeomorphic $M_j$, avoid choice by working
with *all* the homeomorphisms from $X_i$ to $M_j$.)

This condition seems to me far too restrictive. For example one
could have infinite sets of such $M_j$s as long as they came
pre-equipped with a selection of appropriate metrics.

So what I seek are general conditions on such $M_j$'s (or even for
say just rigid metrizable spaces) that permit the selection of a
canonical metric based solely on knowledge of the topology.

If the general question is still too vague, I don't even know the
answer to this: does a compact, rigid space homeomorphic to some
subset of the unit disk in ${\Bbb R}^2$ admit a distinguished
metric (perhaps optimal for some objective function)?

Contrarywise, I'd be interested in models where a countable
disjoint union of rigid metrizable spaces might have no compatible
metric.

Comment: Doesn't the subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ inherit the Euclidean metric from $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Andrej I think we are supposed to forget how the space is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Trevor Wilson has it right!

Comment: I don't understand the sentence beginning "But a metric" near the beginning of your question.  There seems to be a typo or grammatical error.  

Comment: Have now added a few words. Better?

Comment: Still don't understand it, at a purely grammatical level. Should "given" be "give"?

Comment: David, would you mind if I edited your question somewhat? 

Comment: Joel, please go ahead.

Comment: David, I made a suggested edit, trying to make the context a bit clearer. But please feel free to revert/erase/change as you like. 

Comment: @David: I have deleted my answer, but I don't understand why you said that it was "simply incorrect." As far as I can tell, I did not make any false statements (after the edit). 

Comment: Thank you Qiaochu Yuan!  And I do take your point...you made no false statements.  My concern was that an "answer" here purports to satisfy the demands of the question, and that you did not succeed in doing (yet?).  So I feared your leaving it up would turn into a distraction.

Comment: Where you wrote "distance two" I think it would be more precise to say "distance $\ge 1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer the last part of the question:

There is a model of ZF and a set $X$ of countably many topological spaces such that each space is isomorphic to the compact interval $[0,1]$ but the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{x\in X} x$ is not metrizable.

Firstly, there is a weaker version of the Axiom of choice which proposes a choice function only for countable sets of two element sets. This axiom of countable choice for two-element sets is already independent of ZF, as shown in [Thomas J., The Axiom of Choice](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/75/suppl/C), Chapter 4.4.

We want to construct metrizable spaces such that choosing a metric on each space induces the choice of one out of two elements.

Let $S$ be a countable set such that each element of $S$ contains exactly two elements. For each $s=\{a,b\}\in S$ define $y_s$ to be the topological space $s \times [0,1]$ modulo the equivalence relation $(a,1)\sim (b,0), (b,1)\sim (a,0)$. So $y_s$ is homeomorphic to a circle. Let $z_s$ be the universal cover of $y_s$. Then, $z_s$ is homeomorphic to the real numbers. Note that this homeomorphism involves a choice but the $<$-relation can be defined without any choice as the extension of the $<$-relations on $[0,1]$. Let $x_s$ be the two-point compactification of $z_s$, that is adding a point on top and below the other elements with respect to the order. So $x_s$ is homeomorphic to the compact intervall $[0,1]$. Let $X=\{x_s\mid s\in S\}$.

Assume that there would be a metric on $\bigsqcup_{x\in X} x$. Then, for each $s\in S$, the distance $d_s$ of the lowest and highest point in $x_s$ is finite. Therefore, there are points, which have exactly distance $d_s/2$ to the lowest point of $x_s$. We take the lowest of them. This is now a point which comes from the universal cover, so it has a preimage in $\{a\} \times [0,1)$ or in $\{b\} \times [0,1)$. Therefore, we get either $a$ or $b$. So this metric would define a choice function.

I want to add some remarks:

1. It feels quite unlikely to find any topological criteria for metrizable spaces such that there union is metrizable. (An exception would be discrete spaces.) This feeling comes from considering the example given in the problem and this example. Note that this example can be easily generalized to many topological spaces which include a compact interval somewhere.
2. The problem on finding a metric on the union of metrizable spaces reduces to the problem on finding simultaneously a metric on each space:
   If $d_x$ is a metric on $x$, then $(u,v)\mapsto \arctan(d_x(u,v))$ is a metric on $x$ which is bounded by $\pi/2$. Defining
   $$d(u,v) = \begin{cases} \arctan(d_x(u,v)) & \text{ if }u,v\in x\text{ for any  }x\\ \pi &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$
   gives a metric on the union.